# How to create a Form on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

A little more detail. Im a noob when it comes to Sharepoint, was given access today and am, playing around, i am using it as a staorage site for projects, using the calender to manage demo requests etc.

I want users (sales team) to be able to fill out a form with questions like, what is the date of requested demo, what hardware is needed, what dates?  (hence needing to know how to create one). Then when the form is filled out and submitted and if possible approved by me,  an entry is made in the calender and all sales team members are notified that an entry has been made

I have booked a sharepoint course but it is in a months time....

Any help would be great...

Answer (score 0):

The form would just be a list with custom columns added to it.  The list could be based on a Task list (would allow for Outlook integration and alerts [email] for who it's assigned to) or a custom list.

The sales team notification for the calendar entry could be handled by setting up alert notifications for the sales team.

As far as the form (item) being approved and creating a calendar entry, you will either need to code a custom solution (list item event handler) or perform this action manually.

My suggestion would be to play around with the different lists and OOB customizations to determine what will best fit your needs.